# Jquery laravel viewing modal causing 401 logged out

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal-dialog, unauthorized

Im building a web application with laravel, but i am having issues when opening a modal after logging in. It seems JQuery is causing a 401 (unauthorized error) that results in a time out.

It seems that this occures mostly with Google Chrome but happens very inconsistantly. So sometimes when I log in i get a 401 error after opening/loading a modal and sometimes i don't.

The modal I'm opening is being populated with an Ajax call that lists a set of users from a MYSQL database.

I added the error from the console as an attachment. I masked the URL's for privacy reasons. The red one handles the login and the purple one is the url that opens the modal and lists the users
[jquery 401 error on opening modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA9S0.png)

I have no idea how JQuery is causing this 401 error, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Laravel expects a _token parameter whenever it gets a POST request. You typically add it to your forms using blade with `{!! csrf_token !!}`. Using Ajax it is no different. You'll need to add the _token parameter to the request if you are going to do a POST request. You can do so by adding it directly to your Ajax parameters, or by telling jQuery to handle it on all Ajax request by adding this to your layout view `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">;`. And this to your JavaScript.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Make sure it is run before any Ajax request.

This won't add the _param, but it will add a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header to the Ajax POST requests. Laravel will check for the _token param **or** the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` so you really only need one or the other.

If you already added it and still experience this issue, try looking at Laravel's response in your browser "network tab". In Chrome, press F12 to open up the DevTools. Go to the Network tab and refresh your page. On the left panel you'll see all HTTP requests your page made. You can filter the requests for Ajax by clicking the `XHR` filter. Click on your failed request (It will be coloured red). On the right panel you'll see all the request and reponse data. You can click on response to view Laravel's response. The Preview tab will format all HTML/CSS if the response was HTML.

Comment: There were indeed some problems with CSRF tokens. Thx!